# Cannot build angular project

Tags: angular

I run this command to create build on angular project

> ng build
>
> PS C:\wamp64\www\project\frontend> ng build ⠙ Generating browser
> application bundles (phase: building)...fatal error: runtime: cannot
> allocate memory

after that getting this error:

```
runtime stack:
runtime.throw({0x83285, 0x1f})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1198 +0x7
runtime.persistentalloc1(0x1018, 0x40, 0x35b038)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1411 +0x50
runtime.persistentalloc.func1()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1365 +0x2
runtime.systemstack()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_wasm.s:170 +0x2
runtime.mstart()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_wasm.s:28

goroutine 360 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_wasm.s:181 fp=0x4e7318 sp=0x4e7310 pc=0x13a80000
runtime.persistentalloc(0x1018, 0x40, 0x35b038)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1364 +0x2 fp=0x4e7358 sp=0x4e7318 pc=0x10a90002
runtime.(*spanSetBlockAlloc).alloc(0x357d50)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mspanset.go:286 +0x7 fp=0x4e7380 sp=0x4e7358 pc=0x11cb0007
runtime.(*spanSet).push(0x345110, 0xc7bcc0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mspanset.go:124 +0x1c fp=0x4e73e8 sp=0x4e7380 pc=0x11c8001c
runtime.(*mcentral).uncacheSpan(0x3450b8, 0xc7bcc0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:231 +0x1a fp=0x4e7418 sp=0x4e73e8 pc=0x10f0001a
runtime.(*mcache).refill(0x360108, 0x53)
⠹ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...0xa fp=0x4e7478 sp=0x4e7418 pc=0x10eb000a
runtime.(*mcache).nextFree(0x360108, 0x53)
⠸ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...0xa fp=0x4e74b0 sp=0x4e7478 pc=0x10a2000a
runtime.mallocgc(0xc00, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1071 +0x7e fp=0x4e7538 sp=0x4e74b0 pc=0x10a3007e
runtime.growslice(0x5f260, {0x6f0000, 0x80, 0x80}, 0x81)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/slice.go:261 +0x83 fp=0x4e7588 sp=0x4e7538 pc=0x12c60083
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/css_lexer.Tokenize({0x3, 0x6d0cf0, 0x66d9c8, 0x94ba0, 0x66d9e0}, {0x1, {{0x43090d, 0x4a}, {0x0, 0x0}, ...}, ...})
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/css_lexer/css_lexer.go:193 +0xf fp=0x4e7738 sp=0x4e7588 pc=0x194a000f
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/css_parser.Parse({0x3, 0x6d0cf0, 0x66d9c8, 0x94ba0, 0x66d9e0}, {0x1, {{0x43090d, 0x4a}, {0x0, 0x0}, ...}, ...}, ...)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/css_parser/css_parser.go:37 +0x2 fp=0x4e79d0 sp=0x4e7738 pc=0x19a50002
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/cache.(*CSSCache).Parse(0x6b4568, {0x6, 0x66f180, 0x66d950, 0x66d968, 0x6cc980}, {0x1, {{0x43090d, 0x4a}, {0x0, ...}, ...}, ...}, ...)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/cache/cache_ast.go:59 +0x10 fp=0x4e7cb8 sp=0x4e79d0 pc=0x1be60010
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.parseFile({{0xecc68, 0x6651d0}, {0x6, 0x66f180, 0x66d950, 0x66d968, 0x6cc980}, {0xe9670, 0x617500}, 0x6b4540, ...})
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:217 +0xbf fp=0x4e9c08 sp=0x4e7cb8 pc=0x1c7600bf
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_wasm.s:431 +0x1 fp=0x4e9c10 sp=0x4e9c08 pc=0x13d10001
created by github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.(*scanner).maybeParseFile
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1144 +0x3e

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
syscall.fsCall({0x763f7, 0x4}, {0x461b60, 0x5, 0x5})
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/fs_js.go:521 +0x13
syscall.Read(0x0, {0x4cc000, 0x4000, 0x4000})
        /usr/local/go/src/syscall/fs_js.go:389 +0xc
internal/poll.ignoringEINTRIO(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:582
internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0x42c060, {0x4cc000, 0x4000, 0x4000})
163 +⠼ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...0x4c
os.(*File).read(...)
        /usr/local/go/src/os/file_posix.go:32
os.(*File).Read(0x40c018, {0x4cc000, 0x4000, 0x4000})
        /usr/local/go/src/os/file.go:119 +0x10
main.runService(0x1)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:101 +0x23
main.main()
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/main.go:203 +0x8

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
main.runService.func1(0x42e190, 0x414bf0)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:66 +0x3
created by main.runService
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:64 +0xe

goroutine 7 [waiting]:
runtime.gopark(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:366 +0x27
runtime.handleEvent()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/lock_js.go:250 +0x1b
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_wasm.s:431 +0x1

goroutine 8 [chan receive]:
main.(*serviceType).sendRequest(0x42e190, {0x3ac00, 0x54dcb0})
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:163 +0xd
main.runService.func2(0x42e190)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:92 +0x3
created by main.runService
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:89 +0x1e

goroutine 354 [runnable]:
main.runService.func3(0x42e190, {0x481400, 0x3c0, 0x400}, 0x414bf0)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122
created by main.runService
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122 +0x3a

goroutine 353 [runnable]:
main.runService.func3(0x42e190, {0x693000, 0xf30, 0x1000}, 0x414bf0)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122
created by main.runService
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122 +0x3a

goroutine 351 [runnable]:
main.runService.func3(0x42e190, {0x690000, 0x24c, 0x280}, 0x414bf0)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122
created by main.runService
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122 +0x3a

goroutine 350 [chan receive]:
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.(*scanner).scanAllDependencies(0x617880)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1535 +0x1a
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.ScanBundle({0x6, 0x66f180, 0x66d950, 0x66d968, 0x6cc980}, {0xecc68, 0x6651d0}, {0xe9670, 0x617500}, 0x6b4540, ...)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1041 +0x41
github.com/evanw/esbuild/pkg/api.transformImpl({0x6e6000, 0x541}, {0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, {0x0, 0x0}, 0x0, 0x0, ...})
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/pkg/api/api_impl.go:1371 +0xf3
github.com/evanw/esbuild/pkg/api.Transform(...)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/pkg/api/api.go:399
main.(*serviceType).handleTransformRequest(0x42e190, 0x22, 0x6d0570)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:849 +0x28
main.(*serviceType).handleIncomingPacket(0x42e190, {0x5cc300, 0x6b5, 0x700})
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:196 +0x27
main.runService.func3(0x42e190, {0x5cc300, 0x6b5, 0x700}, 0x414bf0)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:123 +0x2
                                                             created by main.runService
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122 +0x3a

goroutine 357 [runnable]:
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.ScanBundle.func2(0x676600, 0x617180)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1026
created by github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.ScanBundle
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1026 +0x3e

goroutine 355 [runnable]:
main.runService.func3(0x42e190, {0x696000, 0xdf2, 0x1000}, 0x414bf0)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122
created by main.runService
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122 +0x3a

goroutine 356 [chan receive]:
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.(*scanner).scanAllDependencies(0x617180)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1535 +0x1a
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.ScanBundle({0x6, 0x66e460, 0x66d188, 0x66d1a0, 0x667a40}, {0xecc68, 0x6648b0}, {0xe9670, 0x616e00}, 0x5fbbc0, ...)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1041 +0x41
github.com/evanw/esbuild/pkg/api.transformImpl({0x6a6000, 0xc8c}, {0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, {0x0, 0x0}, 0x0, 0x0, ...})
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/pkg/api/api_impl.go:1371 +0xf3
github.com/evanw/esbuild/pkg/api.Transform(...)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/pkg/api/api.go:399
main.(*serviceType).handleTransformRequest(0x42e190, 0x28, 0x679170)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:849 +0x28
main.(*serviceType).handleIncomingPacket(0x42e190, {0x697000, 0xdf2, 0x1000})
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:196 +0x27
main.runService.func3(0x42e190, {0x697000, 0xdf2, 0x1000}, 0x414bf0)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:123 +0x2
created by main.runService
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122 +0x3a

goroutine 359 [runnable]:
github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.ScanBundle.func2(0x676c00, 0x617880)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1026
created by github.com/evanw/esbuild/internal/bundler.ScanBundle
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/internal/bundler/bundler.go:1026 +0x3e

goroutine 352 [runnable]:
main.runService.func3(0x42e190, {0x692000, 0xdf2, 0x1000}, 0x414bf0)
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122
created by main.runService
        /Users/evan/dev/esbuild/cmd/esbuild/service.go:122 +0x3a
```

How can i resolve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: You can add a new entry in script section.
Check this link
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408820/building-angular-project-lead-to-heap-out-of-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408820/building-angular-project-lead-to-heap-out-of-memory)

Comment: @AashirAzeem Do i have to edit these lines of code in package.json `"start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
        "test": "ng test"` ?

Comment: Yes you have to. Still having error?

Comment: @AashirAzeem Yes getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Try allocating more memory. You can use `--max_old_space_size` option to specify how much memory `node` command can use.

If you would like to allocate 8GB, try as below.

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build
```

Comment: Thanks i have to update this line in package.json file? `"build": "ng build"`

Comment: Yes you can edit your package.json.

Comment: updated this line but still getting same error `"build": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build",`, i have 8GB ram

Comment: It looks `esbuild` command fails to allocate memory. Unfortunately I can not figure out why it fails...